# Google Analytics - Tracking Unknown

Tags: android, google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api

I have created a testing Google Analytics sample app as directed in on [Google Analytics SDK for Android documentation](http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/android/) and I have initiated Tracking in my code using:

```
tracker = GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance();
tracker.trackEvent(
            "Clicks",  // Category
            "Button",  // Action
            "clicked", // Label
            77);
```

And

```
tracker.trackPageView("/HomeScreen");
tracker.dispatch();
```

I have created a Google Analytics account, In my account if go to Analytics setting tab. I am getting the status as "Tracking Unknown"

I tried clicking on the edit and clicked check status, Then  too I am Getting **"Tracking Not Installed"**

For Reference My code is:

```
public class GAnalytics extends Activity {

  GoogleAnalyticsTracker tracker;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    tracker = GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance();
    tracker.start("UA-19487404-1",20, this);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button createEventButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.NewEventButton);
    createEventButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        tracker.trackEvent(
            "Clicks",  // Category
            "Button",  // Action
            "clicked", // Label
            77);       // Value
      }
    });

    Button createPageButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.NewPageButton);
    createPageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        tracker.trackPageView("/HomeScreen");
      }
    });

    Button quitButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.QuitButton);
    quitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        finish();
      }
    });

    Button dispatchButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.DispatchButton);
    dispatchButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        tracker.dispatch();
      }
    });
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    super.onDestroy();
    tracker.dispatch();
    tracker.stop();
  }
}
```

Please point me where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you started the tracker after your call to `.getInstance()`?
Like this:

```
tracker.start("UA-YOUR-ACCOUNT-HERE", this);
```

You also need to call the following to send the data to Google Analytics:

```
tracker.dispatch();
```

Comment: @cantOna - is the dispatch necessary after a trackEvent()?  In my readings of the doc, it didn't seem so unless one gave a dispatch timeout.  CORRECTION - upon deeper reading, it appears that the dispatch is necessary if you DON'T supply a dispatch timeout.  If a timeout is supplied and there are messages to send, they will be batched.

Comment: Yea I did the same tried manual tracking too.. Used tracker.dispatch

Comment: I am getting 11-08 20:14:26.813: WARN/googleanalytics(456): org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond

Comment: That WARN looks suspiciously like an error returned from your phones' networking (do you have networking turned on in the phone?)

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The dispatch is only necessary if you have not set an interval. I was not sure if you did.I guess I would wait for a while as KevinDTimm says, as there may delays up to 24 hours or more before you can see the data in the analytics dashboard.

Answer (score 2):

By default, analytics data is one day behind, are you modifying the reporting dates to show the current day?  If so, bear in mind that a 30 minute delay is not at all unusual.

Comment: Hi Kevin, I did not modified any date anywhere, In my system now its 8:00 pm, but I am getting Tracking Not Installed (Last checked: Nov 8, 2010 6:38:06 AM )  when clicked on Check Status

Comment: Hi Kevin, If I use tracker.dispatch(); I am getting 11-08 20:14:26.813: WARN/googleanalytics(456): org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond

Comment: Vinayak - click on your webpage link in analytics, it will take you to a dashboard.  that's where you can change the date (upper right corner of the webpage).  Also, keep your post information together by editing your question - to that, where I you getting that error?

Comment: hey Kevin is it true that after visiting my app in my device it takes one day time to display the status in my google analytic account..and why "Tracking Not Installed" shown in my status appears in my account

Comment: @Anshuman - it used to be that all data is a day behind.  I have not checked it recently.  I would guess that's why (on the first day) you'll see the message you saw.  After that, all should be well.

Comment: Hey kevin yesterday i asked u about the tracking event..today the status icon changes and its say "receiving data" but there is no data display in the dashboard although i visited my app 3-4 times yesterday.

Comment: @Anshuman - Sorry, I don't know why, you'll have to ask google (or search) to figure out what's wrong

Comment: yeh i have found in google..here they say that after the tracking code is installed it takes 24 hours to retrive the data..is t tha way it happen

Comment: @Anshuman - It seems then that it takes almost 2 days to get the first data, then it's all 1 day behind.

Answer (score 1):

Refer below code

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

   GoogleAnalyticsTracker tracker;


      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        tracker = GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance();

        // Start the tracker in manual dispatch mode...
        tracker.startNewSession("UA-33332745-1", this);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button createEventButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.NewEventButton);
        createEventButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          public void onClick(View v) {
            tracker.trackEvent(
                "Clicks",  // Category
                "Button",  // Action
                "clicked", // Label
                77);       // Value
          }
        });

        Button createPageButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.NewPageButton);
        createPageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          public void onClick(View v) {       
            // Add a Custom Variable to this pageview, with name of "Medium" and value "MobileApp"
            tracker.setCustomVar(1, "Medium", "Mobile App");        
            tracker.trackPageView("/testApplicationHomeScreen");
          }
        });

        Button quitButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.QuitButton);
        quitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
          }
        });

        Button dispatchButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.DispatchButton);
        dispatchButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          public void onClick(View v) {
            tracker.dispatch();
          }
        });
      }


      protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // Stop the tracker when it is no longer needed.
        tracker.stopSession();
      }
    }
```